# Docusign APi with RUby: IS there a way to download a document with all the tab content populated

Tags: ruby, docusignapi

I need to download an envelope from docusign by populating the tab data in ruby on rails.

I have used get_combined_document_from_envelope but it does not seems to get all the data.

```
  def method_name 
      output_pdf = docusign.get_combined_document_from_envelope(
         envelope_id: document.external_key,
         local_save_path: "docusign_docs/file_name.pdf",
         return_stream: false
       )
  end
```

I need the output file to have all the tabs populated.

Answer (score 0):

The pdf would have the data inside the document as part of the completed doc (assuming it's visible). If you want to get the data downloaded separately, you would need to use API calls to get the envelope and get the tabs information. see this https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/features/tabs